# Specific words from a text file with PLY

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a lexical analyzer for determined words that are in a .txt file, for this I declare determined words reserved and I try to print only the selected words on the screen, but the result I get is that it takes all the words in the txt file and prints them. I've been following the tutorial and the official Ply documentation in http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6 but I still don't achieve my goal. Could someone help me with this? Thank you very much.

```
import ply.lex as lex
import re
import os
import sys

reservadas = {
    'if' : 'if',
    'then' : 'then',
    'else' : 'else',
    'while' : 'while',
 }

tokens = ['ID','NUMBER','PLUS','MINUS','TIMES','DIVIDE',
        'ODD','ASSIGN','NE','LT','LTE','GT','GTE',
        'LPARENT', 'RPARENT','COMMA','SEMMICOLOM',
        'DOT','UPDATE'
        ] + list(reservadas.values())

#tokens = tokens+reservadas

# reservadas = {
    # 'begin':'BEGIN',
    # 'end':'END',
    # 'if':'IF',
    # 'then':'THEN',
    # 'while':'WHILE',
    # 'do':'DO',
    # 'call':'CALL',
    # 'const':'CONST',
    # 'int':'VAR',
    # 'procedure':'PROCEDURE',
    # 'out':'OUT',
    # 'in':'IN',
    # 'else':'ELSE'
# }

#tokens = tokens+list(reservadas.values())

t_ignore = '\t '
t_ignore_PLUS = r'\+'
t_ignore_MINUS = r'\-'
t_ignore_TIMES = r'\*'
t_ignore_DIVIDE = r'/'
t_ignore_ODD = r'ODD'
t_ignore_ASSIGN = r'='
t_ignore_NE = r'<>'
t_ignore_LT = r'<'
t_ignore_LTE = r'<='
t_ignore_GT = r'>'
t_ignore_GTE = r'>='
t_ignore_LPARENT = r'\('
t_ignore_RPARENT = r'\)'
t_ignore_COMMA = r','
t_ignore_SEMMICOLOM = r';'
t_ignore_DOT = r'\.'
t_ignore_UPDATE = r':='

def t_ID(t):
     r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
     t.type = reservadas.get(t.value,'ID')    # Check for reserved words
     return t

def t_newline(t):
    r'\n+'
    t.lexer.lineno += len(t.value)

#dsfjksdlgjklsdgjsdgslxcvjlk-,.
def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'\//.*'
    r'\/*.*'
    r'\*/.*'
    pass

def t_NUMBER(t):
    r'\d+'
    t.value = int(t.value)
    pass

def t_error(t):
    print ("----- '%s'" % t.value[0])
    t.lexer.skip(1)


while True:
    tok = analizador.token()
    if not tok : break
    print (tok)
```

the output I get with the above code is:

```
LexToken(ID,'FSR',1,3)
LexToken(ID,'testing',1,7)
LexToken(ID,'sketch',1,15)
'---- '
'---- '
LexToken(ID,'Connect',3,28)
LexToken(ID,'one',3,36)
LexToken(ID,'end',3,40)
LexToken(ID,'of',3,44)
LexToken(ID,'FSR',3,47)
LexToken(ID,'to',3,51)
LexToken(ID,'V',3,55)
LexToken(ID,'the',3,58)
LexToken(ID,'other',3,62)
LexToken(ID,'end',3,68)
LexToken(ID,'to',3,72)
LexToken(ID,'Analog',3,75)
'---- '
.
.
.
.
LexToken(ID,'Serial',21,694)
LexToken(ID,'print',21,701)
----- '"'
LexToken(ID,'Analog',21,708)
LexToken(ID,'reading',21,715)
----- '"'
'---- '
LexToken(ID,'Serial',22,732)
LexToken(ID,'println',22,739)
LexToken(ID,'fsrReading',22,747)
'---- '
'---- '
LexToken(ID,'LEDbrightness',26,898)
LexToken(ID,'map',26,914)
LexToken(ID,'fsrReading',26,918)
'---- '
LexToken(ID,'analogWrite',28,996)
LexToken(ID,'LEDpin',28,1008)
LexToken(ID,'LEDbrightness',28,1016)
'---- '
LexToken(ID,'IF',29,1034)
'---- '
LexToken(if,'if',30,1038)
'---- '
LexToken(ID,'delay',31,1044)
'---- '
----- '}'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

my expectation for the exit would be this:

```
LexToken(ID,'IF',29,1034)
'---- '
LexToken(if,'if',30,1038)
```

I am analyzing a code of arduino, and all those words are comments, but I only need you to look for the conditionals if or IF, or other reserved words like for, but the main idea is that with a list of reserved words you identify them and show me only those selected

Comment: Your title should be in English

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I already solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard tokens that are not in your 'reserved' list, adjust the `t_ID` function like so:

```py
def t_ID(t):
     r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
     reserved_type = reservadas.get(t.value, False)
     if reserved_type:
         t.type = reserved_type
         return t  # Return token with reserved type
     return None # Discard non-reserved tokens
```

Additionally, your comment token function is probably misapplied here.

```py
def t_COMMENT(t):
    r'\//.*'
    r'\/*.*'
    r'\*/.*'
    pass
```

You can't use multiple rules or span a rule over multiple strings like this. Because the docstring (which `ply` uses to get the regex) will only contain the very first string.

Secondly, I think the regex needs adjusting for comments, assuming you're tokenizing C or a C-like language. Particularly, it needs to account for the possibility that comments span multiple lines.

To fix, apply the following for dealing with comments:

```py
def t_block_comment(tok):
    r'/\*((.|\n))*?\*/'
    tok.lexer.lineno += tok.value.count('\n')
    return None  # Discard block comments "/* comment */"

t_ignore_comment = r'//.*'  # ignore inline comments "// comment"
```

You may also need to apply the regex multiline flag:

```py
analizador = lex.lex(reflags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Lastly, your `t_ignore_DIVIDE = r'/'` may be preventing your comment rules from applying, too. Consider ordering this *after* the comment rules.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, the modification that you indicate throws me an error, it tells me that name 'reserved_value' is not defined,it is missing to compare reserved_value with something?, excuse me if I do not understand very well that line of code.

Comment: @andbrs appologies. I just fixed a typing error in my answer. It should have been `reserved_type` not `reserved_value`.

Comment: Thank you very, I was trying to understand the library and I had been trying to solve the problem for hours, you always learn something new. Again thank you very much =).